# Bean annotations like @ManagedProperty and @PostConstruct doesn't work when manually instantiating the bean from another bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, annotations, managed-bean

I instantiated a request bean from another request bean,

```
new LoginManager();
```

But the property which is annotated with `@ManagedProperty` doesn't get the value from the asked reference, only in case of instantiation through the above way. It just contains `null`, causing NPE later in code. Also `@PostConstruct` won't be invoked. Why is it so & how should I deal with this?

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginManager")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginManager {

    private String userid;
    private String password;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{currentSession}")
    private UserSessionManager userSession;

}
```

But `userSession` can't read from the session scoped bean when this bean was instantiated  using: `new LoginManager();`

However I can read the value using `FacesContext`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not manually instantiate (manage) beans using `new` operator. You should let JSF do the job of managing the beans and instead grab the JSF-managed (JSF-instantiated) instance.

Either by `@ManagedProperty` in the bean where you need it:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{loginManager}")
private LoginManager loginManager;
```

Or by invoking EL programmatically (which is pretty borderline in your particular case):

```
LoginManager loginManager = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{loginManager}", LoginManager.class);
// ...
```

If you insist in instantiating and managing the bean yourself, you should do all dependency injections yourself, also invoking the `@PostConstruct` yourself, if any, and finally also putting the bean in the desired scope yourself. E.g.

```
LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager();
loginManager.setUserSession(userSession);
// Now use reflection to find and invoke @PostConstruct method.
// Finally store in the map which conforms the bean's scope.
externalContext.getRequestMap().put("loginManager", loginManager);
```

This boilerplate is exactly what JSF is supposed to take away from your hands. Make use of it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! In both the method (using @ManagedProperty & `evaluateExpressionGet`), if the beans already existed,they  will retrieved right ? So i dont need to even check whether or not the bean has been instantiate before & I can directly use , right?

Comment: That's correct. JSF will only create it if it doesn't exist in the scope yet, else it will just return the existing instance.